# Why is Git committing to the wrong repository?

Tags: git, github

I am in Chapter 2 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I typed the following into the command line:

```
$ git init 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$  git remote add github https://github.com/themaktravels/demo_app.git

fatal: remote github already exists.

$ git push -u github master

Username: 
Password: 

To https://github.com/themaktravels/first_app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/themaktravels/first_app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I saw that I got a fatal error before that noted that Github exists, but I thought this was okay because I had committed in Git earlier in a different repository.  I noticed that when I `$ git push -u Github master`, the outcome was that git was trying to commit in the wrong repository (first_app.git) rather than the newly created repository (demo_app.git).  Why is this happening?

Before trying to commit, I typed in the following:

```
$ cd ~/rails_projects
$ rails new demo_app
$ cd demo_app
```

and then edited my gem file and everything seemed fine. Until I ran into this git issue.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this bit here:

```
$  git remote add github https://github.com/themaktravels/demo_app.git

fatal: remote github already exists.
```

If you already have a remote called `github`, then the `git remote add` command won't change the existing setting. Use `git remote -v` to see your current remotes and where they point to. I suspect you already have a remote called `github` that points to `https://github.com/themaktravels/first_app.git`.

Comment: I just tried, `$ git remote -v` and it looks like I also have a github for demo_app.git... here is the output: `github git@github.com:themaktravels/demo_app.git (fetch)` `github git@github.com:themaktravels/demo_app.git (push)` `origin git@github.com: (fetch)` `origin git@github.com: (push)` .  Does this mean that before I create a new repo, I have to rename "github" to something else?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a remote named "github", which points to first_app,  so when you try to add the new one, which points to demo_app, it fails.

It looks like you were trying to initialize Git in a repository that already exists and already had a remote. Make sure you do this in a fresh directory.

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
>   Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.

Like it is trying to tell you, the push is trying to cause a non-fast-forward update.